# How to forcefully download PDF/image/video/audio in Angularjs using link

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome, download

I want to download file forcefully. but in new chrome update, file open on browser rather than download in case of Image/Video/Audio/PDF 
HTML:

```
<a href="" ng-click="downloadFile()">Click to download file</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.downloadFile = function () {   
        fileInfo = {
            path: collection.file_path,
            file_name: collection.file_name
        };
        payOutService.getSignedUrlFromS3ByPath(fileInfo).success(function (response) {//response is simply file link
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.download = collection.file_name;
                link.href = response;
                link.click();
            }

        });
};
```

**Note: For checking this issue you have to update your google chrome(Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)).**
How Can I do this. I have checked approximately every response on stackoverflow.com but there is no solution of my issue because it come under new update of chrome.  I appreciate every response. Thanks Ahead.

Comment: Since the download attribute only works for same origin I'd imagine that you might have to download the data with JS, make a Blob, and download that instead. But it seems like a bad idea due to the complexity/time required to implement/cross-browser concerns. Alternatively you can create a proxy on your server to the download which would be preferable imo.

Comment: In older version of chrome same code can able to download all type of file but in newer version of chrome open file into browser. But my requirement is very clear to download every file directly without opening.

Comment: Do you know the exact release note about this? I would suggest putting a PDF on the same domain and seeing if that works, if it does then you can set up a proxy endpoint to s3

Comment: I have mention the exact version of chrome in question. And I have try with putting pdf in same domain but still not work

Comment: yes download attribute only work with some browser such as chrome.

Comment: normal :   <a href='http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf' download>click to download</a> this html used to download any pdf file but now you click on link then it will open directly.

Comment: Not in my habits to suggest a library here.. but last time i tried this kind of things, i ended up using FileSaver.js, going cross-browser consistently was such a pain.. updated chrome and tested my script, it still works. There seem to be an [angular version here](http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/) (i have not tested it)

Comment: @ Kaddath I think this is not work in case of big videos and audios. Do you realy think so.